# Getting "io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException" In Gatling when ramping up load with high user count

Tags: performance-testing, gatling, scala-gatling, gatling-plugin

I want to test my APIs with high load. I have written load config like below:

```
setUp(
    scn.inject(
      nothingFor(2 seconds),
      constantUsersPerSec(250) during (300 seconds),
      rampUsersPerSec(50) to (100) during (60 seconds),
    ).protocols(httpConfig)
```

When I want to run 250 user and want to ramp it upto 300 seconds only, its giving me loads of errors. Can someone suggest to bypass the errors? I want to generate 1000calls/sec onto API but with this setup its barely going upto 200 calls/per in monitoring tool. I want to put 500K calls in 5-10 min duration but looks like basic one with 50K-70K is not working and giving errors/exceptions

I tried with `constantUsersPerSec` along with `rampUsersPerSec`

Comment: Are you using a proper setup? Hopefully you're not using your Windows laptop with antivirus on and on wifi.

Comment: @StéphaneLANDELLE I am using windows remote VDIs to hit this load. Any other option you would want to suggest for this ?

Comment: On prem Linux server (hence no anti-virus that breaks load). Gatling Cloud if you want plug and play and don't need on prem.

Comment: @StéphaneLANDELLE anyhow its not achievable on windows ? does open source gatling supports heavy load ? like if i want to hit 1000 calls/sec on to my APIs ? currently i am only able to reach 200 calls/sec which is not of any use? or its mandatory to choose gatling enterprise for this load also ?

Comment: Your issue is most likely that your Windows machine is not tuned for load testing (anti-virus, throttled TCP stack, etc). Haven't used Windows for ages, so can't help with that. Anyway, not a Gatling issue, but a Windows OS tuning one. Ask your ops people in your company. I suggested Gatling Cloud so that you don't have to configure your machines if you don't know how to.